# Loop throug form fields on angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to set pristine all the form fields but this way doesn't work

```
  angular.forEach($scope.userForm, function (item) {
        item.$setPristine();
      });
```

on this form `<form novalidate name="userForm" ng-submit="formSubmit()">`

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
$scope.userForm.$setPristine();
```

To set the form pristine.